# How to optimize the connection to the database when using codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have some problem with my website because the traffic is so full,

I build the website using codeigniter and use autoload to database like this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','cart','user_agent');
```

I try to optimize with make a core, the name is MY_Model like this

```
<?php
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        $this->db->close();
    }
}
```

when i use like shop_model, i call like this

```
class shop_model extends MY_Model {
```

but the results are the same and sometimes the max_user_connection error

the question is, how do I optimize database connections like this? because this is the source code that has been used operationally with extensive coverage

Comment: Codeigniter can't deal with it. you should have proper indexing to your database.

Comment: You either have poorly structured queries that takes unnecessary long time to execute, or you simple have too much traffic for your site. Do some proper debugging and see where the issue is. It has most likely not to do with your database _connection_, but your architecture/queries or lack of database indexes. If all checks out, then you need to think about upgrading your server. However, it's impossible for us to know since we don't know your setup.